# json function not being executed in vs 2010

Tags: javascript, json, saas

json function not being executed,,, 
 Does it have calling method error,, i am brand new to programming like a Kid,,, thanks in advance

```
$.getJSON('http:/ *some nvarchar* ame', { diseaseName: dsName }, function (data) {
  var tasks = $.parseJSON(data.d);

  alert("Sued");

  $.each(tasks, function (key, value) {
    $('<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed="true"><h3>' + value.diseaseName + '</h3><ul data-role="listview" id="diseaseListView" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"><li><strong>Description:</strong><span>' + value.description + '</span></li></ul></div>').appendTo('#DiseasesList');
  });

});
```

Comment: You have to use FireFox or Chrome to debug the this.
First you have to see if variable dsName is defined.
Then you should set a break point and see if variable data has anything in it and see if server returned something.

Comment: thanks alot,,, worked on internet explorer....chrome sucks on that,,,

Comment: @Scription please post it as answer....i already waited for answer from you....

Comment: posted as an answer as requsted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use FireFox or Chrome to debug the this. First you have to see if variable dsName is defined. Then you should set a break point and see if variable data has anything in it and see if server returned something.